Simplification of $\frac{1}{x} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+a^2n^2}$ in terms of trigonometric functions
I'm trying to simplify the expression $\frac{1}{x} + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+a^2n^2}$ in terms of trigonometric functions. I know that
$\coth(x) = \frac{1}{x} + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+n^2\pi^2}$ but seem to end up with a missing factor of $2$ in front of the sum if I try to similarly rearrange $\frac{1}{x} + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+a^2n^2}$. Is there a closely related expression out there for $\frac{1}{x} + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+a^2n^2}$?

Multiply the top and bottom by $\pi^2/a^2$ first:
$$
\frac{1}{x} + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+a^2n^2}
= 
\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2\pi^2}{a^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\frac{\pi^2}{a^2} x^2+\pi^2 n^2}
= 
\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2\pi^2}{a^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2}
$$
Multiply and divide the top by $\pi/a$ now:
$$
\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2\pi^2}{a^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2}
= \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2\pi}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi a x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2}
$$
To make the $1/x$ match, multiply the top and bottom by $\pi/a$:
$$
\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2\pi}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi a x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2}
= \frac{\pi/a}{\pi x / a} + \frac{2\pi}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi a x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2}
$$
Factor out $\pi/a$:
$$
\frac{\pi/a}{\pi x / a} + \frac{2\pi}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi a x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2}
= \frac \pi a \left( \frac{1}{\pi x / a} + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi a x}{\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)^2+\pi^2 n^2} \right)
$$
Seems like we get, then, $\frac \pi a \coth \left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)$, if I'm not mistaken.

Oh nice, yeah that actually seems to come out perfectly. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot for the help!
